# HtmlAgilityPack clean inner text from html

Tags: vb.net, dom, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, strip-tags

I have this html. I'm trying to get its InnerText without any tags in it,

```
<h1>my h1 content</h1>
<div class="thisclass">
<p> some text</p>
<p> some text</p>
    <div style="some_style">
    some text
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- some script -->
        </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='some_script.js'></script>
    </div>
<p> some text<em>some text</em>some text.<em> <br /><br /></em><strong><em>some text</em></strong></p>
    <p> </p>
   </div>
```

What am trying to do is get the text as the user would see it from the class thisclass.
I want to strip any script tag, and all tags, and just get plain text.

This is what am using:

```
 Dim Tags As HtmlNodeCollection = root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='thisclass'] | //h1")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (warning c# code ahead):

```
foreach(var script in root.SelectNodes("//script"))
{
    script.ParentNode.RemoveChild(script);
}

Console.WriteLine(root.InnerText);
```

This gave me the following output:

```
my h1 content some text some textsome text    some textsome textsome text. some text
```

Hope this helps.